# Use of "from" with two consecutive dates

Tags: grammar

Is it right to say,

> Preparation leave for the exams will be from 2nd  to 3rd Oct.

Is it okay to use 'from' when the dates are consecutive?

Comment: Why do you think it might be a problem?

Comment: I thought it would be better to use 'and' since the dates are consecutive. However, I was wondering if I could say it this way by using 'from'. Turns out it can be spoken right? There's nothing wrong

Comment: I would say *"Preparation leave for the exams will be **[on] the** 2nd **and** 3rd **of** October."*

Comment: Greybeard, I thought about it the same way. Actually, my friend used this sentence during a talk, and I don't know why it sounded odd to me. Ergo I joined here, to look for what was right.

Comment: Greybeard's "and" construction is certainly an option, but I don't think there's a reason that the given example is wrong. It might raise follow-up questions about exactly *what time* of each day, but it's not inappropriate to use "from A to B" to indicate a range when A and B are neighboring units.

Comment: @Andy but wouldn't "from the 2d to the 3rd October" need clarification as to whether it includes those days or not? (joke)

Comment: @PapaPoule Joking aside, that's why you so often see "from X to Y *inclusive*," which IMO ought to go without saying.

Comment: @AndyBonner "from X to Y" and "between X and Y" are often conflated, but the latter is ambiguous about whether it's inclusive or exclusive.